# How to get args from a decorator that uses class

Tags: python, discord, python-decorators

I was trying to make a loop function that uses class, and to make it easier i think i will make it as decorator, but there are a few problem when i tried my code,

1. When i tried this code, it says that I'm missing 1 required argument and it's "self"
2. I tried doing this to my code, but realized that it used `__call__`, which i don't want to because it will executed at the time the function is called. (I dont know if this true)

And this is how i used it, and https://hastebin.com/onozarogac.py (for the full code):

```
@looper(seconds=3) # this code is from other class
def print(self):
    print(len(self.cache.get_available_guilds_view()))

self.print.start() # and by using this to trigger it
```

```
def looper(seconds):

    def decorator(func):
        return Looper(func, seconds * 1000)
    return decorator

class Looper:
    def __init__(self, fn, seconds):
        self.fn = fn
        self.interval_ms = seconds / 1000
        self.time_last = time()
        self.started = False

    def loop(self):
        time_now = time()
        if time_now >= self.time_last + self.interval_ms:
            self.fn()
            self.time_last = time_now
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def set_interval_ms(self, interval_ms):
        self.interval_ms = interval_ms / 1000

    def set_interval_s(self, set_interval):
        self.interval_ms = set_interval

    def get_interval_ms(self):
        return self.interval_ms

    def get_interval_s(self):
        return self.interval_ms * 1000

    def start(self):
        self.started = True
        while True:
            if self.started:
                self.loop()
            else:
                break

    def stop(self):
        self.started = False
```

Its giving me the TypeError which:

```
TypeError: print() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: Can you show the error, it'll will be easier to answer

Comment: @HIMANSHUPANDEY i edited the code, and showed the error, could you take a look at it?

Comment: what is `self` from line 5? Outside the class and the function you did not define `self`.

Comment: @Cedric you've written `self.print.start()`, are you sure `print` function has member function `start`? Also, `self` should be used inside classes, it has no meaning outside 'class definitions' unless name of your class itself is 'self'

Comment: Also, can you please provide code of that `other class`.

Comment: @HIMANSHUPANDEY I've edited and provided the full code, and about the `self.print.start()`, I'm not really sure but it should have the start function from the looper decorator i guess?

Comment: For a temporary fix, instead of decorating, you can directly call the member function of that class at the first line of print method, because this is a recognized alternative way to using decorators.

Answer (score 0):

convert looper function to this

```
from functools import wraps

def looper(seconds):
    def inner(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return Looper(func, seconds * 1000)
        return wrapper
    return inner
```

Comment: It doesn't work and still giving me the same error which is `TypeError: print() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`